# How Can I change style in jqGrid frozen columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I made the grid without frozen columns of `jqGrid`.

And I added frozen columns method in `gridComplete`

```
gridComplete: function() {$(this).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');},
```

After this in frozen columns styles disappeared.
I dynamically change styles in `loadComplete` function, for example:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#fff0f5");
```

Can I fix this problem?

Comment: Put your entire example on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I configured new event and function, and move entire codes into the new function as following. Working well.

```
loadComplete: function() {
(A) .......... => move to (B) 
}

$("#gridid").on('jqGridAfterGridComplete.setFrozenColumns', function(e) {
(B) .......... <= moved from (A)
});
```